# Список из nil вместо данных

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, golang, orm, gorm

В документации приведён [пример](https://gorm.io/docs/advanced_query.html#Find-To-Map).

```
var results []map[string]interface{}
db.Table("users").Find(&results)
```

Делаю аналогично:

```
  var results []map[string]interface{}
  c.db.Table("project").Find(&results)
```

И получаю `[]map[string]interface{}{nil}`

Comment: Добавьте .Debug() и посмотрите запрос SQL, а так же запустите его в БД для получения результатов.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov запрос корректный. Проблема скорее всего в том, что это gorm.v1, где такого функционала нет.